# What's the point of returning via the Function() Constructor

Tags: jquery

The JQuery ParseJSON code has the following structure:

```
function( data ) {
        // regular expression manipulations involving data
        return (new Function( "return " + data ))();
}
```

and I'm wondering why not use `return data` instead? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data is a string, so if you say return data, it will just return the same string what was passed to it...

```
function( data ) {
        // regular expression manipulations involving data
        return (new Function( "return " + data ))();
}
```

In the above snippet we are creating a new function which returns an object like if `data` was `'{"test":"somevalue"}'` then you have `"return" + '{"test":"somevalue"}'` so the concatenated string is `"return {"test":"somevalue"}"`(`new Function('return {"test":"somevalue"}')()`) which is like returning an object.